# Docker - PHP does not use the allocated resources

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

I have a Wordpress website running on PHP7.3.

The website runs perfectly on production in a Kubernetes environment.
Currently, we do not use Docker for our development environment, just a simple LAMP.

We would like to setup a development environment with Docker.
But our Websites take too much time to load (and timeout) when running inside Docker.

After checking the host metrics (my computer) PHP uses around 0.1% of the CPU, when checking the container metrics, it looks like that Docker is completely idle.

> The container that should be using resources is lexon-websites-workspace_wordpress-b2b_1

[image: Result of docker stats]

When pointing to an empty index.php, I get an instant response.

- Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
- elementary OS 5.1.6 Hera Linux 5.3.0-62-generic

Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress:5.3.2-php7.3-apache

RUN apt update && apt install python-pip git libzip-dev zlibc zlib1g libmemcached-dev -y

RUN git clone -b php7 https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached /usr/src/php/ext/memcached \
    && cd /usr/src/php/ext/memcached && git checkout master \
    && docker-php-ext-configure /usr/src/php/ext/memcached \
        --disable-memcached-sasl \
    && docker-php-ext-install /usr/src/php/ext/memcached \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/php/ext/memcached

RUN echo "memory_limit = 4096M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memory-limit-php.ini
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? If an empty `index.php` yields a direct response, I would assume that something in your application blocks the servers

Comment: @NicoHaase I am getting the exact same problem with a clean Wordpress. I will use xdebug to debug that

Comment: It appears that the problem come from W3 Total Cache. I still have a slow site when not using but it's way better. And the container use some CPU know !
It looks like that the culprit is Memcached, I will open an other question and close this one. https://imgur.com/a/E4iQINV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I found that the problem was coming from W3TC trying to access to the Memcached server.

The W3TC plugin was trying to access to our production Memcached server (inaccessible from outside) and result to a silent timeout.